# CDN help, who should I go with and any alternatives?

Tags: cdn

I have a image hosting site which has grown rapidly over the last 3months and I feel I need to look at a CDN. The dedicated server the site runs on is located in Holland (Europe) whilst image load times seen fine here I have reports that in the Americas and Asia loads times have become noticeable slower than usual.

So what I want is a CDN network worldwide at least in Europe, Americas and Asia. Pricing must be inline with rackspace solution I have found below. Must have a PHP API. Must not only server files but also offer storage.

The site currently needs 160GB of storage (this is growing by roughly 700mb per day) and at least 2600GB of bandwidth (prices below are based on American traffic)

Options I'm looking at: http://www.rackspace.co.uk/cloud-hosting/cloud-products/cloud-files/
 - Storage 11p and Bandwidth 12p per GB
 - PHP API
 - Worldwide storage included

Can anyone recommend another company or another set-up?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369/whats-the-best-cdn-for-image-hosting-on-a-high-volume-web-site) over at Stack overflow should provide you with a good run down

Answer (score 1):

I have used these for serving audio & images:

- Amazon S3/Cloudfront: locations in North and South America, EUR, and ASIA
- MaxCDN/NetDNA: has USA/EUR/ASIA locations

Comment: +1 For MAXCDN.  Using them for 2 years and everything is awesome.